# Monitoring changes to roles in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

We are looking to set up a solution to monitor primarily the Global Admin role in Azure AD, so if a user is added to or removed from the role an e-mail is sent to a specific mailbox.

On our local AD we have a working solution for this, but I can't seem to find a similar solution for AAD.

In the Office 365 Security & Compliance Center > Alerts > Alert Policies there is a policy called "Elevation of Exchange admin privilege" which basically does what I want, except it only targets the Exchange Admin role.

I've tried creating a new policy from scratch, but as far as I can tell there is no way to choose to target a specific role. There is only the "Granted Exchange admin permission" and nothing really comes up when I search for "role" or "admin" in the "Activity is" drop down.

I've also looked at the MCAS (MS Cloud App Security) policies but nothing there seems to be what I need either.

I found this article: [Monitor Office 365 admin role changes in all customer tenants](https://gcits.com/knowledge-base/monitor-office-365-admin-role-changes-in-all-customer-tenants/) but it seems to be geared more towards multitenant environments and requires quite a bit och additional setup. I was hoping there was a simpler solution for a single tenant environment.

Kind regards

Comment: Are you still looking for any help in this question

Comment: I am actually... I added a similar question to Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/questions/1027303/alert-if-a-user-is-added-to-global-admin-in-azure-ad) with the information gleaned from this and got a little more info, but still not where I had hoped to be.

Comment: Currently, it is not possible through portal please raise [feedback request](https://feedback.azure.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have MCAS, I think it's possible that you have PIM as well (privileged identity Management. it requires aad P2 skus. But assuming you do, then it's very simple to do this. You would just go into the PIM in azure, click azure ad roles, click manage roles, choose the global admin role, Click role settings, and you will see options like this
[image]

If you don't have PIM, then it becomes quite a bit more complicated but could probably be less complicated than your example, you could set up log analytics to ingest azure ad data, and using a query pull out that information (role assignment event for example), then you could set up an alert in monitor referencing a log analytics workspace. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-analyze-activity-logs-log-analytics

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

We are using PIM on all administrative roles.

I was under the impression that this configuraition only warned on changes to the administrative roles under PIM, not if a user was added to the general or open Global Admin role.

Was I mistaken in this belief or does this only cover assignments/elevations via PIM?